# Saving contents from inside a div to a PDF file

Tags: javascript, save, stickynote

I implemented jStickyNote to a website [here](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/notes.html).

If the user tries to close or refresh the page, a warning pops up and takes care of that.

However, I would also like to add functionality to allow a user to save the contents within a div, in this case, the "content" div.

Is it possible to save these sticky notes to a PDF? Or save the content div as an image?

All I can seem to find are solutions for saving to a database, but I don't want that. These need to be able to save to an individual's machine.

```
<!--Content Start-->
<div id="content" style="width: 1013px; height: 1350px; background: url(images/Whiteboard.png) no-repeat center center;">

        <ul class="stickynote">
            <li id="newsticky"></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

Try out it's functionality and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: what tool do you use to create PDFs

Comment: I don't know... Every machine here has MS Word. I thought maybe the content could be placed in a Word doc and the user could manually save to a PDF, or if it could be done automatically, that would be great.

Comment: Look you are going in a wrong direction ... to be able to do this using javascript you will need to init a new ActiveXObject and this doesn't work except for IE and required the client machine to have MS Word installed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7sw4ddf8(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: If it helps any... all the machines here use IE8 as the primary corporate browser.

Comment: what server code are you guys using

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34933/discussion-between-webfrogs-and-mina-gabriel)

Comment: I'm still in the Chatroom waiting for your feedback.